# Creating a queue of asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have an asynchronous function which makes a request, `makeRequest(): Promise<string>`. Basically, I want to make a way of queuing calls to this function so that requests are only being made one at a time.

```js
async function queueRequest(): Promise<string> {
  await ... // some code to make sure all previous requests have already been completed
  const result = await makeRequest();
  return result;
}
```

What is the best way to achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To do it you need to use an array where you shift a task and you push the new incoming task.

I would use [`fastq`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastq) to avoid to reimplement all the logic to manage a queue data structure.

Here an example:

```js
const queue = require('fastq')(worker, 1)

function worker (params, cb) {
  console.log('Executing ', params)
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, { i: params })
  }, Math.random() * 100)
}

function makeRequest (params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    queue.push(params, function (err, result) {
      if (err) { return reject(err) }
      resolve(result)
    })
  })
}

async function queueRequest (index) {
  const result = await makeRequest(index)
  // manage the result
  return result
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  queueRequest(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is from the [MDN page on Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). They have a couple more examples directly following the one I have below too in order to expand a little upon it.

> Sequential composition is possible using some clever JavaScript:

```js
[func1, func2, func3].reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve())
.then(result3 => { /* use result3 */ });
```

> Basically, we reduce an array of asynchronous functions down to a promise chain equivalent to: Promise.resolve().then(func1).then(func2).then(func3);

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/why-using-reduce-to-sequentially-resolve-promises-works/) is a good article on using `reduce()` to achieve this goal of sequential Promises. It does a good job of walking through it and explaining each step better than the MDN docs.

Comment: How would I go about this in a way in which each `queueRequest()` call returns the result when it eventually comes, and I can queue a new request at any point in time?